# javascript count match string length

Tags: javascript, indexing, match

I Have this example :
https://jsfiddle.net/xqdwL914/1/

```
<div id="test">bar <i>def</i>ghij<br>bar <i>def</i>ghij</div>
```

I Want to find "bar" index and length in multi occurrence like this :

```
var node = document.getElementById('test');
var text  = node.textContent;
var re = /bar/g;
while ((match = re.exec(text)) != null) {

alert("match found at: " + match.index+ " length: " +match.length);

 }
```

the output :

match found at: 0 length: 1

match found at: 11 length: 1

Why the length is "1" it should be "3" as three character of the word "bar"
and how i get the last index of each match word bar ????

Comment: so how i would count it each iteration ??

Comment: when i use it like this : alert("match found at: " + match.index+ " length: " +text.match(re).length); it looping infinity ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

> If the match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has the matched text as the first item

```
var text  = 'bar <i>def</i>ghij<br>bar <i>def</i>ghij';
var re = /bar/g;
while ((match = re.exec(text)) != null) {
    console.log("match found at: " + match.index+ " length: " +match[0].length);
}
```

output:

```
match found at: 0 length: 3
match found at: 22 length: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Returned `match` is an array. I understand that you are looking for the length of the `match` string at the first position (`match[0]`):

```
while ((match = re.exec(text)) != null) {
    alert("match found at: " + match.index+ " length: " +match[0].length);
}
```

[image]